# TSQL need to return last day of month only, how do I drop year, month & time?

Tags: t-sql, date, datetime, sql-drop

I am writing a function in T-SQL returning the last day of the month regardless of the date input.

Here is my code:

```
Alter Function dbo.FN_Get_Last_Day_in_Month2
(@FN_InputDt    Datetime)
Returns smalldatetime
as 
Begin

Declare @Result  smalldatetime
Set    @Result =

       case when @FN_InputDt <> 01-01-1900 then 
       DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(M, 0,@FN_InputDt)+1, -1)
       Else 0 End

Return @Result

End
```

The code is not working correctly, here is a test that shows the bad behavior:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_get_last_day_in_month (07-05-2010)
```

Here is the (incorrect) result:

```
2010-07-31 00:00:00
```

Comment: Why is the sample output wrong, isn't the 31st the last day of July?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**What is 07-05-2010...May 7th or July 5th?** You need to use a safe date format, take a look at [Setting a standard DateFormat for SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/setting-a-standard-dateformat-for-sql-se)

example from [How to find the first and last days in years, months etc](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/How_to_find_the_first_and_last_days_in_years,_months_etc)

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME
SET @d = '20100705'  -- notice ISO format

SELECT
    DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, @d), 0) AS FirstDayOfYear,
    DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, @d)+1, -1) AS LastDayOfYear,
    DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, @d), 0) AS FirstDayOfQuarter,
    DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, @d)+1, -1) AS LastDayOfQuarter,
    DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @d), 0) AS FirstDayOfMonth,
    DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @d)+1, -1) AS LastDayOfMonth,
    @d - DATEDIFF(dd, @@DATEFIRST - 1, @d) % 7 AS FirstDayOfWeek,
    @d - DATEDIFF(dd, @@DATEFIRST - 1, @d) % 7 + 6 AS LastDayOfWeek
```

for just the day use day or datepart

```
 select DAY(getdate()),
     DATEPART(dd,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thank you SQLMeance I have two quick questions. One how do you call a select statement in a function?  Two how do I filter for the '01011900' date?

Answer (score 1):

Cast the return value to a SQL datetime type, and then call the "DAY" function to get the day in as an integer.  See the function reference here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176052.aspx

Not sure which database you're using, but this should be a standard function across all databases.

Comment: thank you warriorpostman, i better undestand the DAY function now! I had searched for datetime, datepart and so forth, but for some reason did not think to check Day.

Answer (score 0):

I'd return a DATETIME, I've had trouble with SMALLDATETIME in the past.

```
DECLARE @Result DATETIME

SET @Result = DATEADD(m , 1, @FN_Input);

RETURN CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATEADD(d, DATEPART(d, @Result) * -1, @Result) AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```

Also, I think you may be a victim of SQL's complete disregard of date formatting. Always, always, always, when typing a string into test a SQL function use the following format;

'05 Jul 2010'

Your function probably works but it interpreted your date as 5th July - not 7th May.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '20130624';
SELECT Day(EOMONTH ( @date )) AS LastDay;
GO
```